# Rails 3: radio button for each element in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I loop through an array of objects and create a radio button or check box for each of them in a form?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Radios

```
<% ["Peter", "Jhon", "Carl"].each do |item| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :name, item %> <%= item %><br />
<% end %>
```

check boxes:

```
<% ["Peter", "Jhon", "Carl"].each do |item| %>
  <%= f.check_box :name, item %> <%= item %><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you have your items are in a hash, for instance in a constant that you store in the class:

```
# fruits.rb

# Fruit has a field 'kind' which is stored as an integer but displayed as a string:
KINDS={0=>'bananas',1=>'plantains',2=>'baby bananas'}


#fruits/new.html.erb

<% Fruit::KINDS.each do |val,name| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :kind, val %> <%= name %><br />
<% end %>
```